# Swagger UI - can't enable JSON editor for the request body

Tags: json, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I have some issue to make it work,
according to following link below, the JSON editor for the request body (disabled by default).

https://github.com/jensoleg/swagger-ui

How can I enable it?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. Add the following into index.html in the `new SwaggerUi({})` constructor:

```
docExpansion: "none",
sorter: "alpha",
jsonEditor: true,
defaultModelRendering: 'schema',
showRequestHeaders: true
```

Comment: I had the same issue.I am using Swagger 2.0 and the thing that fixed it for me was including the "name" parameter in the body of the JSON.