# Enable Json Editor using Swagger-UI

Tags: json, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

How can I use the Json Editor using the following github (https://github.com/jensoleg/swagger-ui)?

What codes do I need to use in order to enable JSON editor for the request body?

Tried changing my code but it is not working for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The page you linked to contains "JSON editor configuration example". Have you tried it?

Comment: Where do I copy and paste the example code in the github?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swagger UI - can't enable JSON editor for the request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37441859/swagger-ui-cant-enable-json-editor-for-the-request-body)

Comment: @Helen I tried the example but its saying that my 'JSONEditor' is not defined. Do you have any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

JSON form editor is not supported in Swagger UI 3.x and 4.x. There's an [existing feature request](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/2771).

Comment: Can you offer the link to the existing feature request?